# Do we really need a materials tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see a few questions using the [materials](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) tag. This seems to me like the tools tag. I suppose it can give a question context. It just seems like a tag that adds very little to the question. The current questions using tag are as follows

- [Is PVC pipe safe to use for a dust collection system?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/is-pvc-pipe-safe-to-use-for-a-dust-collection-system)
  I guess you could argue that the OP is asking about PVC "materials"
- [How can I safely move complete 4 ft x 8 ft sheets of plywood alone?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/how-can-i-safely-move-complete-4-ft-x-8-ft-sheets-of-plywood-alone)
  I added the [plywood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plywood) to this question but don't see how the materials tag fits.
- [How do I calculate the weight threshold for plywood boxes/cabinet carcasses?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/534/how-do-i-calculate-the-weight-threshold-for-plywood-boxes-cabinet-carcasses) Again, I added the [plywood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plywood) to this question.

I am not trying to burn the tag or anything because I am sure it is justafiable. I would just like to know what the guidelines for using that tag would be. What would the appropriate usage for this tag?

Comment: Not sure, it seems like a good one to have.  But not thinking of a good example right now to give why.

Comment: @bowlturner TBH I don't really like the tools tag... I can't see many _useful_ applications for it.

Comment: I tend to think more tags are better.  But tools tells me it more of a focus on tools, materials on materials and technique on how to do things.

Comment: I suppose. I think rob made a similar case for tools. Like I said I don't get it but I'm fine with more tags. Rather have more now than decide to go retag later.

Comment: I know it's come up on several occasions, but the idea I've seen repeated since even before I started pushing it is that it's easier to delete a tag later than it is to add one later and retag all the relevant questions.

Comment: @rob I've always been a pusher of that mentality. I just don't get this tag is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's come up on several occasions, but the idea I've seen repeated since even before I started pushing it is that it's easier to delete a tag later than it is to add one later and retag all the relevant questions.

[materials](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) potentially has many uses, including the following:

1. low-rep users can tag a question for which the material they're using doesn't already have a tag
2. it's a nice catch-all blanket term if we don't think a particular material deserves its own tag
3. at present it seems to be a useful marker for questions which are not properly tagged
4. general advice on asking for an appropriate material for a project

It may be that we don't know yet how it *should* be used, and that's ok, as long as its use isn't more harmful than it is helpful. We can always go back and remove the tag from some questions once we refine its purpose.